# FreeNAS volume size is less than a dataset on the volume

Tags: freenas

I've created a volume through the ZFS Volume Manager (zpool1) with 8 disks of WD Red 4TB in a raidz2 configuration, and then created a zfs dataset (windows-dataset on it.

Why is the size of the volume zpool1 not equal to the entire disk space? How can the dataset be bigger than the volume it's on?

Here's an image to illustrate.
[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

So I found out why FreeNAS (or rather ZFS) does things this way. I'll try to explain it as best I can.

The volume has a maximum of available space obviously. In this case it's 20,3TiB.

When I created a dataset on the volume, that dataset also had 20,3TiB available, because there was no data on the volume. Apparently, a dataset in ZFS [acts somewhat like a filesystem](http://blog.pluralsight.com/zfs-nas-setup-guide).

However, all of the space is only available to the first filesystem that claims it. Which means that when I started transferring files to my windows-dataset, ZFS "gave away" all of the space of my volume to the windows-dataset. I could have set a quota on the dataset, but I didn't because I wanted all the space available for the dataset. This also means that the other datasets can only have a maximum size of the space that's left on the volume (i.e. that isn't used).

So that's why the volume size only shows 8,8TiB. That's all it has left to give away. Makes sense when you think about it. And know about it ;)

I haven't been able to test the following, but I suspect that when I start adding files to the other two datasets, the windows-dataset size should start decreasing from 20,3TiB as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the volume size has been communicated wrong.. Have you tried removing the dataset and making a new one? Are all the parameters the same for this dataset as the other two datasets?

Failing that, I would lookup what you can do with zfs in shell, there may be something that can solve the problem like unmounting and remounting the dataset.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the dataset. I did actually try removing and adding it before I found out the answer I just posted here.

Comment: I'm glad you sorted your problem.. I have looked at my FreeNAS and my overall free space is shown on all the datasets "free space" column and you were right about putting data onto one dataset and then creating others after. Mine is the same, never noticed that!